# How to return unknown column names based on a condition in an Access 2016 query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with historical values, and some have columns where all the values are null. I'm trying to delete all the columns where all the values are null. In this dataset, the null values are represented by ".." and there are 733 records.

My problem is not knowing how to refer to an unknown column name. The query below is my latest attempt to identify if I can even select the correct information before I start dropping columns.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*)
FROM table
WHERE * = ".."
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "dataset" - do you have a single table (then simply querying each column manually would be the fastest option) or many tables?

Comment: One table. I would query each column but I was hoping there is a quicker solution as there over 100 columns.

Answer (score 1):

As Olivier wrote, SQL alone won't do it. The easiest way is to loop the fields collection and use DCount on each field, with a criterium like `[field name] <> '..'` to find all columns that **only** have `'..'`.

```vb
Sub AnalyzeTable()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim td As DAO.TableDef
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    Dim sCrit As String
    Dim n As Long

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set td = db.TableDefs("tHistorical")
    For Each fld In td.Fields
        ' only check text columns
        If fld.Type = dbText Or fld.Type = dbMemo Then
            ' For each field, count the records *not* containing '..'
            sCrit = "[" & fld.Name & "] <> '..'"
            n = DCount("*", "tHistorical", sCrit)
            ' if that number is 0, the column only contains '..' and can go
            If n = 0 Then
                ' this will go into the Immediate window, use Ctrl+G to open it
                Debug.Print fld.Name
            End If
        End If
    Next fld

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot accomplish this task with SQL. You could open a recordset and test all the columns for each record by looping through the Fields collection.

But if you have only 733 records, the easiest way is to open the table in access, select all the columns and apply Sort Ascending. You will then see the empty rows being displayed first. Delete them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Yea... you can't just have it return records where a single column is nothing but `'..'` values. You'll need to query the columns.

Something like

```
Select ' 
    count(*), 
    sum(iif(f1='..',1,0)), 
    sum(iif(f2='..',1,0)),
    ...
FROM table
```

And see if any of the columns match the total, then you have a column to work with.